# How to return amount of excluded rows in postgresql using OFFSET

Tags: sql, postgresql, pagination

I have a query that looks like:

```sql
SELECT  
  userid,
  name,
  lastname
  location
  count(*) OVER() AS totalrows
  FROM Users 
  ORDER BY userid
  limit 1 offset 5
```

`OFFSET` will change programatically depending on the values of a paginated query that comes from my website.
Now, I need to know the amount of excluded rows by my query. With this info plus `totalrows` my website will know if I can fetch more events and exactly how many were fetched in total (implying there are no new records, but i'm ok with that for now).

Considering that my table has 10 rows in total, if I ask postgres to explain my query I can see that sort returns 6 rows which is `total amount of excluded rows (5) + returned rows (1)`

[Query explained](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6v6qq.png) (can't embed images due to low rep)

I've tried searching how to get this data, but didn't find it. Esentially, how can I get this number? Or is there a better approach to solve my issue?

Comment: If you sent the `OFFSET 5` you know the answer: 5. Where is the problem? By the way, fetching the total count will lead to bad performance, particularly if you do that for every page you query.

Comment: I'm working with node-postgres and want to return the result + `nextOffset` which would be the number I want. Site will use nextOffset only if the user presses "load more results" but doesn't change filters or stays in the page. If Something happens I need to reset the offset number. This is why I don't truly know OFFSET from the backend point of view ahead of time